# Iphone , how to read mp3 google tts in iPhone

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech, google-translate

I use the sample code in this link

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/06/revisiting-old-post-streaming-and.html

its work for all http link mp3 file but its not work for

```
@"http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=";
```

because it is html 5 page can i help me please  for read this link

Comment: Why are you trying to stream an MP3 from a Google-translated HTML page?  Why not just go directly to the source?

Comment: because this is only html 5 mp3 tage not any directly to source

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm interested in this issue...